# Will switch to MyISAM Engine help to improve the speed of reading operations?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, myisam

I'm currently have a few tables with `InnoDB Engine`. 10-20 connections are constantly inserts data into those tables. I use `MySQL RDS` instance on AWS. Metric shows about 300 Write IOPS (counts/second). However, INSERT operations lock the table, and if someone want to perform a query like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table;` it could literally take a few hours for the first time before MySQL cache the result.

I'm not a DBA and my knowledge about DB are very limited. So the question is if I'll switch to MyISAM Engine will it help to improve the time of READ operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT COUNT(*) without WHERE is bad query for InnoDB, as it does not cache the row count like MyISAM do. So if you have issue with this particular query, you have to cache the count somewhere - in a stats table for example.

After you remove this specific type of query, you can talk about InnoDB vs MyISAM read performance. Generally writes do not block reads in InnoDB - is uses MVCC for this. InnoDB performance however is very dependent of how much RAM you have set for the buffer pool.

InnoDB and MyISAM are very different in how they store data. You can always optimize for one of them and knowing the differences can help you in designing your application. Generally you can have as good performance for reading as in MyISAM in InnoDB tables - you just can use count without where clause, and you always should have a suitable index for where clauses, as in InnoDB table scan will be slower than in MyISAM.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should stick with your current setup. InnoDB is supposed not to lock the table when inserting rows, since it uses the MVCC technique. On the other hand, MyISAM locks the entire table when new rows are inserted.

So, if you have many writes, you should stick with InnoDB.

Answer (score 1):

Innodb is a better overall engine in general. There are some benchmarks out there that put read operations in myiasm a little ahead of innodb. However, if your site is big enough to notice this performance difference, you should be on innodb anyway because of all the other efficiencies.  Innodb alone wins because of the row level locking instead if table level locking in myiasm when backing up your database.